# CA certificate not found error - Service Error 401002

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

1.Create CA certificate using create cert chain.  
2.Uploaded CA certificate to certificates section under DPS.  
3.Generated verification code.  
4.Generated verification certificate using verification code as common name using createverificationcert  
5.uploaded verification certificate and verified successfully. 
6.created group enrollment with Root certificate. 
7.generated device specif pfx using createdevicecert 
8.tried to provision device using device specific certificate it throws Service Error 401002 Certificate not found (X509 certificate sample)

Note : However it is working for openssl. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you refer to any document?

Comment: @TonyJu yes, https://github.com/rwatjen/AzureIoTDPSCertificates